# have to get the id of each divs under the main div based on class name

Tags: jquery

Hi in my page i have one main div it is having many child divs. i want to find the each div ids based on the class name i.e.,

```
<div id="main"> 
 <div id="child1" class="child"> 

</div>
 <div id="child2" class="child"> 

</div>
 <div id="child3" class="child"> 

</div>
</div>
```

i'm trying to get the id of the each div by using the following script. But it is viewing only the first div id

```
$("#main").each(function() {
    var val = $(this).find(".child").attr("id");
     alert(val);//displays only child1
 });
```

Can any one suggest me how can i get the each div ids

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you are looping through main div instead of it's child div's that's why its' only getting the first child div id

you can do it like this

```
$.each($("#main .child"),function()
{
   alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZPzcq/)

Answer (score 1):

This is another way to do the same thing. Note the use of `this.id` in place of `$(this).attr('id')`. Simpler/cleaner to read.

```
$('#main .child').each( function(){
    alert(this.id);
});
```

Link to [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/utewoz/1/edit)

Note: It is preferred to use `.prop()` rather than `.attr()` in the latest versions of jQuery